# Gcc Error: [enum] field declared as a function

Tags: gcc, struct, enums, compiler-errors, c11

I'm getting this odd error...

```
jos_log.c:16:13: error: field '_errno' declared as a function
    ERRNO    errno;
             ^
```

...when I compile this code:

```
typedef enum ERRNO_
{
   /* ... */
}
ERRNO;

typedef struct LOG_ENTRY_
{
   char *   message;
   ERRNO    errno;    // <--- Error here
   ERR_SEV  severity;
}
LOG_ENTRY;
```

Any ideas on what could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translation unit includes `errno.h`, through which [`errno`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errno) is already
defined as preprocessor macro, whose definition provokes the error.

In my case, with `gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~16.04) 5.4.1`, the file:

```
#include <errno.h>
typedef int ERR_SEV;
typedef enum ERRNO_
{
   x
}
ERRNO;

typedef struct LOG_ENTRY_
{
   char *   message;
   ERRNO    errno;
   ERR_SEV  severity;
}
LOG_ENTRY;
```

yields the similar error:

```
a.c:12:13: error: field ‘__errno_location’ declared as a function
    ERRNO    errno;
             ^
```

as result of:

```
#   define errno (*__errno_location ())
```

within `<bits/errno.h>`, within `<errno.h>`. Without `#include <errno.h>`,
no error.

Unless you have made a typo in posting the disgnostic, this would suggest
that *your* `<errno.h>` imports the definition:

```
#define errno (*_errno ())
```

The solution is not to use `errno` as your field name.

Comment: That was it! Thanks!